# Reserve current VIP on VM Azure

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, azure

I'm trying to reserve the current VIP on my Virtual Machine. I don't want to create a new IP I want to use the current VIP. I think this is possible since 1 or 2 months ago.
This is the code I ran:

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "vip01" -Location "West Europe" -ServiceName "myservice"
```

But I allways get this error:

```
    VERBOSE: 13:53:59 - Begin Operation: New-AzureReservedIP
New-AzureReservedIP : BadRequest : Cannot reserve the ip of deployment sticketin.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "vip01sticketin" -ServiceName "st ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureReservedIP], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.NewAzureReservedIPCmdlet

VERBOSE: 13:54:32 - Completed Operation: New-AzureReservedIP
```

Any tip to reserve the current IP?

Comment: did you try my suggestion in the other thread about upgrading powershell? Check your version at powershell with "(get-module azure).version".

Comment: I have version 0.95. I think is the last version

Comment: is this a new VM or do you have it for a long time? the api of the cloud service could be outdated but usually there's a specific error regarding this scenario. It usually says "the cloud service is running an old version of the api and must be restarted to update". You could try to deploy a new VM just to test VIP reservation to be sure it's something related to this Cloud service and not powershell

Comment: My VM have about 2 or 3 months. 
The only error related with this command is the one that I put on my post. I will now create a new VM and then try to reserve the IP. Note I used the web panel to create the VM not the powershell

Comment: It works on a new VM, any tip to make it work on the old VM. I really don't want to reset the IP on the current VM

Comment: yea but i'm afraid you will have to. Try restarting using the portal (not from Windows). A restart won't affect your current VIP only shutdown but i think only deallocating would fix the problem.

Comment: I shutdown and restart the VM, I lose my ip but now I can run all the commands. I hate this things in Azure